# connection string error

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have a connection string like this

```
 <add name="rackleyConnectionString1" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\rackley.mdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=Password"
      providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

Now I copied that mdb file into my sql server. Now I changed connection string to this

```
<add name="rackleyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ODO-SRV004;Initial Catalog=rackley;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

when I run the program it shows error: "OLE DB provider was not specified in the connection string. An example would be Provider=SQLOLEDB"

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: What version of SQL server and what platform does the application run on?

Comment: A must have in your favorites : http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are opening sql connection as below

```
Dim cn As SqlConnection= New SqlConnection(sConn)
```

and not

```
Dim cn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(sConn)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You misplaced \ instead of /

```
<add name="rackleyConnectionString1" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:/rackley.mdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=Password"
  providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

I always used /. please try this

Answer (score 0):

```
<add name="rackleyConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=SQLOLED;Data Source=ODO-SRV004;Initial Catalog=rackley;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
```

Try this connection string hope this helps.